# JsonResponse option parameter

Tags: json, laravel

In controller i have:

```
return response()->json(
    [
        'number' => (float)8
    ],
    Response::HTTP_OK,
    [],
    JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION
);
```

This is output:

```
{
    "number": 8
}
```

Is it possible to get `8.0`?
This working good:

```
json_encode(['number' => (float)8],JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION);
```

UPDATE:
when i set `response()->json` from above to `$variable` and then `print_r($variable)` i get this:

(so it looks like it working, but with return in browser i get still 8 not 8.0)

```
Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse Object
(
    [data:protected] => {"number":8.0}
    [callback:protected] => 
    [encodingOptions:protected] => 1024
    [headers] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag Object
        (
            [computedCacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                    [no-cache] => 1
                    [private] => 1
                )

            [cookies:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [headerNames:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => Cache-Control
                    [date] => Date
                    [content-type] => Content-Type
                )

            [headers:protected] => Array
                (
                    [cache-control] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => no-cache, private
                        )

                    [date] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Thu, 08 Feb 2018 11:27:34 GMT
                        )

                    [content-type] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => application/json
                        )

                )

            [cacheControl:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [content:protected] => {"number":8.0}
    [version:protected] => 1.0
    [statusCode:protected] => 200
    [statusText:protected] => OK
    [charset:protected] => 
    [original] => Array
        (
            [number] => 8
        )

    [exception] => 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
json_encode(['number' => number_format(8, 1)]);
```

If number is coming as a string, use `(float)$stringNumber` instead of `$stringNumber`

Comment: problem is that i get this value from outside api. It's returned always as string and its possible to get example 5.000005 and i don't want to round it

Comment: @BolekLolek if it's **always** a simple string like `5.000005`, just serialize the string without any conversion.

Comment: Yes, but when I get only 5 i need to output 5.0. So i want to do it without big change in code (condition to check if it have dot or not).

Comment: @BolekLolek in this case, check if it's an integer first with something like `if ((int)$string == (float)$string)` and do the conversion for integers only.